# How does a magnetic field push/pull/carry electronic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

When an electron is not moving it has an electronic field. When an electron moves it creates a magnetic field. Why can emf travel or oscillate when the magnetic field gets involved?

Comment: Maxwell-equations define their effect (how the electric field generates magnetic field and vice versa). This results mainly an oscillation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an electron is not moving it has an electronic field.

At any time the electron has two fields.  And electric field from the electric charge and a magnetic field from the [electrons magnetic dipole moment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment).

> When an electron moves it creates a magnetic field.

Let us  talk  about two  different observable phenomena.  The first is the movement of electrons in coils. Usually the magnetic dipole moments of  electrons are distributed randomly. In a coil the moments of the moving electrons are aligned and produce a  common magnetic field.  This 2nd phenomenon is the induction of a secondary magnetic field from the primary field. Any magnet approached to another body with magnetic characteristics will align the magnetic fields of this body and will get aligned by this body.  In any case you can say that the electron has intrinsic properties of a magnetic field and it is able to align the magnetic field in other particles.

> Why can emf travel or oscillate when the magnetic field gets involved?

Let us take the example of the moving electrons in the coil. When ever an electron moves in circles it radiates. This we call an electromagnetic radiation.  This radiation consists of photons which have both an oscillating electric and magnetic field. Photons are travelling in vacuum at a constant speed of approx. 300.000 km/h, the speed of light.